# Merging table depending on the same key

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I want to merge two `PHP` arrays to third one and I want to depend them on the same key `data`. I've got `data` key in two arrays and I want stay with this. I want be depend on First `array`. I mean I load first array to `final_array()`, next I adding third key as `ESTYMACJA` from second `array` but to the same `data` from already loaded `data` key in `final_array()`. If there is no `data` key in `final_array()`, algorithm should add this key to `final_array()`, add `WYKONANIA` and copy `ESTYMACJA`. If it possible I would have also copied `ESTYMACJA` to the rest of `data` keys. I will show what I mean in `final_array()` expectation.

1st array:

```
$my_array=[
    ['data'=>'2017-11-27','ESTYMACJA'=>5000],
    ['data'=>'2017-11-30','ESTYMACJA'=>9000]
];
```

2nd array:

```
$new_array=[
    ['data'=>'2017-11-01','WYKONANIA'=>3],
    ['data'=>'2017-11-02','WYKONANIA'=>10],
    ['data'=>'2017-11-03','WYKONANIA'=>303],
    ['data'=>'2017-11-04','WYKONANIA'=>327],
    ['data'=>'2017-11-05','WYKONANIA'=>652],
    ['data'=>'2017-11-06','WYKONANIA'=>812],
    ['data'=>'2017-11-07','WYKONANIA'=>817],
    ['data'=>'2017-11-08','WYKONANIA'=>870],
    ['data'=>'2017-11-09','WYKONANIA'=>1070],
    ['data'=>'2017-11-10','WYKONANIA'=>1199],
    ['data'=>'2017-11-11','WYKONANIA'=>1206],
    ['data'=>'2017-11-12','WYKONANIA'=>1220],
    ['data'=>'2017-11-13','WYKONANIA'=>1421],
    ['data'=>'2017-11-14','WYKONANIA'=>1440],
    ['data'=>'2017-11-15','WYKONANIA'=>1904],
    ['data'=>'2017-11-16','WYKONANIA'=>1910],
    ['data'=>'2017-11-17','WYKONANIA'=>1962],
    ['data'=>'2017-11-18','WYKONANIA'=>2234],
    ['data'=>'2017-11-19','WYKONANIA'=>2305],
    ['data'=>'2017-11-20','WYKONANIA'=>2325],
    ['data'=>'2017-11-21','WYKONANIA'=>2250],
    ['data'=>'2017-11-22','WYKONANIA'=>2263],
    ['data'=>'2017-11-23','WYKONANIA'=>2821],
    ['data'=>'2017-11-24','WYKONANIA'=>2890],
    ['data'=>'2017-11-25','WYKONANIA'=>3411],
    ['data'=>'2017-11-26','WYKONANIA'=>3443],
    ['data'=>'2017-11-27','WYKONANIA'=>3501],
    ['data'=>'2017-11-28','WYKONANIA'=>4032]
];
```

final_array() expectation:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [data] => 2017-11-01
            [WYKONANIA] => 3
            [ESTYMACJA] => 5000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [data] => 2017-11-02
            [WYKONANIA] => 10
            [ESTYMACJA] => 5000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [data] => 2017-11-03
            [WYKONANIA] => 303
            [ESTYMACJA] => 5000
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [data] => 2017-11-04
            [WYKONANIA] => 327
            [ESTYMACJA] => 5000
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [data] => 2017-11-05
            [WYKONANIA] => 652
            [ESTYMACJA] => 5000
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [data] => 2017-11-06
            [WYKONANIA] => 812
            [ESTYMACJA] => 5000
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [data] => 2017-11-07
            [WYKONANIA] => 817
            [ESTYMACJA] => 5000
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [data] => 2017-11-08
            [WYKONANIA] => 870
            [ESTYMACJA] => 5000
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [data] => 2017-11-09
            [WYKONANIA] => 1070
            [ESTYMACJA] => 5000
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [data] => 2017-11-10
            [WYKONANIA] => 1199
            [ESTYMACJA] => 5000
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [data] => 2017-11-11
            [WYKONANIA] => 1206
            [ESTYMACJA] => 5000
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [data] => 2017-11-12
            [WYKONANIA] => 1220
            [ESTYMACJA] => 5000
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [data] => 2017-11-13
            [WYKONANIA] => 1421
            [ESTYMACJA] => 5000
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [data] => 2017-11-14
            [WYKONANIA] => 1440
            [ESTYMACJA] => 5000
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [data] => 2017-11-15
            [WYKONANIA] => 1904
            [ESTYMACJA] => 5000
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [data] => 2017-11-16
            [WYKONANIA] => 1910
            [ESTYMACJA] => 5000
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [data] => 2017-11-17
            [WYKONANIA] => 1962
            [ESTYMACJA] => 5000
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [data] => 2017-11-18
            [WYKONANIA] => 2234
            [ESTYMACJA] => 5000
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [data] => 2017-11-19
            [WYKONANIA] => 2305
            [ESTYMACJA] => 5000
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [data] => 2017-11-20
            [WYKONANIA] => 2325
            [ESTYMACJA] => 5000
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [data] => 2017-11-21
            [WYKONANIA] => 2250
            [ESTYMACJA] => 5000
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [data] => 2017-11-22
            [WYKONANIA] => 2263
            [ESTYMACJA] => 5000
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [data] => 2017-11-23
            [WYKONANIA] => 2821
            [ESTYMACJA] => 5000
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [data] => 2017-11-24
            [WYKONANIA] => 2890
            [ESTYMACJA] => 5000
        )

    [24] => Array
        (
            [data] => 2017-11-25
            [WYKONANIA] => 3411
            [ESTYMACJA] => 5000
        )

    [25] => Array
        (
            [data] => 2017-11-26
            [WYKONANIA] => 3443
            [ESTYMACJA] => 5000
        )

    [26] => Array
        (
            [data] => 2017-11-27
            [WYKONANIA] => 3501
            **[ESTYMACJA] => 5000**
        )

    [27] => Array
        (
            [data] => 2017-11-28
            [WYKONANIA] => 4032
            [ESTYMACJA] => 5000

        )

    *[28] => Array
        (
            [data] => 2017-11-30
            [WYKONANIA] => 4032
            [ESTYMACJA] => 9000

        )
```

This code is already what i've done but im stuck right now.

```
$x = 0;
while ($x<count($final_array))
{
    if ($new_array == null) {
    break;
    }
    else {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($new_array); $i++) {
            if ($final_array[$x]['data'] == ($new_array[$i]['data']) {
                $final_array[$x]['WYKONANIA'] = $new_array['WYKONANIA']; 
            }
            else {
                array_push($final_array, "data", $new_array[$i]['data']);
                array_push($final_array, "WYKONANIA", $new_array[$i]['WYKONANIA']);
                array_push($final_array, "ESTYMACJA", $final_array[$x]['ESTYMACJA']);
            }
        }
    }
    $x++;
}

$myArray - first array
$new_array - second array
$final_array - final array.
```

Comment: The foreach is the wrong syntax and your logic is wrong.  You don't want to check `$final_array[$x]['data'] == ($new_array[$i]['data'])` this is only comparing one index of the array.  You need to check the entire $final_array to see if it contains the matching data value.

Comment: Sorry, there should be `for` loop instead of `foreach`, my mistake

Comment: ....So... the default `ESTYMACJA` value comes from `$my_array[0]['ESTYMACJA']` (`5000`)? and the default `WYKONANIA` value comes from the previous element's `WYKONANIA` value in `$new_array` (`4032`)? This logic is very hard to follow (and I've read your question many times now). Please clarify the logic in this task what determines the currect default values.

Comment: @mickmackusa It should do like this, I will try show it on another example: DATA: 2017-11-15, ESTYMACJA: 500 [next index] DATA: 2017-11-20 ESTYMACJA: 1000. So final array should look like this: DATA: 2017-11-15 ESTYMACJA: 500, DATA: 2017-11-16, ESTYMACJA: STILL 500 etc to DATA: 2017-11-20 and now ESTYMACJA changing to 1000. I need that ESTYMACJA stays in this date range between 2017-11-15 and 2017-11-19.

Comment: Comments are a horrible place to dump code lines.  Please edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
// sort my_array in descending order of dates
rsort($my_array);

foreach($new_array as &$x) {
   foreach($my_array as $i) {
     // Because your dates have a different format, convert them to timestamp
     if(strtotime($x['data']) > strtotime($i['data'])) {
       $x['ESTYMACJA'] = $i['ESTYMACJA'];
       break;
     }
   }
}
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/912792)

Answer (score -1):

This will help

```
function merge_by_keys(){
    $arr = func_get_args();
    $num = func_num_args();

    $keys = array();
    $i = 0;
    for ($i=0; $i<$num; ++$i){
        $keys = array_merge($keys, array_keys($arr[$i]));
    }
    $keys = array_unique($keys);

    $merged = array();

    foreach ($keys as $key){
        $merged[$key] = array();
        for($i=0; $i<$num; ++$i){
            $merged[$key][] = isset($arr[$i][$key]) ? $arr[$i][$key] : null;
        }
    }
    return $merged;
}
```